# How can I make symfony skip over a url that reports "empty module and/or action after parsing url"?

Tags: .htaccess, module, symfony1, action

I am not able to reach a specific URL, because symfony assumes there should be a route set up for it.

I have specified in .htaccess that all urls in this directory are ignored. It seems to work except one specific URL.

In .htaccess, I have attempted to have symfony exlude this URLs from this directory by using:

```
    RewriteRule ^shop/.*$ - [PT,L]
```

However, I continue to receive the empty module and/or action error when visiting a particular URL in this directory.

The error received is:
Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/shop/modules/checkout/googlecheckout/xml.php" (/).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony only processes a request when the url points to a file that is not found. Make sure

```
/shop/modules/checkout/googlecheckout/xml.php
```

is accesible.

With the default configuration the path to the file should be

```
symfony2_root/web/shop/modules/checkout/googlecheckout/xml.php
```

you can test this by creating a test file in your web directory then try to access that file
by simply accesing

```
domain/test.php
```

I am assuming you are using Symfony2 because of the tag in the question. You mention modules, but as far as I know modules is not a terminlogy used in Symfony2.

Comment: Actually it was supposed to be just Symfony.  Not sure why 2 was appended to the tag.  But I checked the location and even echoed some text.  When doing this it accessed the file without trouble.  It seems that it's when Google is trying to access that it gets
"Sending failed with HTTP response code: 401. Response body was: Failed to Get Basic Authentication Headers."  Google Checkout says to check that it has access with the correct merchant ID and password.  I have checked those, and they are absolutely correct.  Thank you for your answer.  It seems now that this question has changed.